# NVIDIA Tesla K80 vs M60, if electricity and capital wasn't a factor

Tags: mining-profitability, gpu-mining, gpu

If I have a setup where electricity and capital are unlimited, which GPU would be more efficient at mining cryptocurrency (such as Ethereum) between the NVIDIA Tesla K80 and the NVIDIA Tesla M60? I know that the M60 is the newer one, is it more efficient though?

Comment: You will probably get a better answer concerning Ethereum on ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible, I tried it for lulz in the cloud (wasted free credits), and it failed to do anything significant, you may find https://github.com/nanopool/ewbf-miner is the better implementation if you want to try, seems to run best on nVidia kit in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If the GPUs are based on the same architecture, it's usually enough to just look at the number of CUDA cores to see which one is better (but don't forget to look at the memory requirements for mining a certian cryptocurrency). M60 and K80 are different generations though, and if you can't find any info about their hashrate on the internet, you'd have to test it yourself.
Considering the very high prices of these high-end GPUs like M60/K80, you might want to consider buying a gaming card like 1070/ti, 1080/ti, 2070, ...